# Deleting .AppleSetupDone in /var/db/ will delete my iCloud account?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, icloud

I need to know that if I deleted the .AppleSetupDone file from my MacBook, is it going to delete my iCloud account too or is it only going to delete administration account?

Answer (score 1):

The .AppleSetupDone file will not delete either the admin account or the iCloud account. See this article: ["How to Re-Run the OS X Setup Assistant"](http://www.theinstructional.com/guides/how-to-re-run-the-os-x-setup-assistant) This will just allow another admin account to be setup.

Comment: i know but the new admin account won't have any iCloud account on it right ?

Comment: The new admin account can optionally be linked to iCloud. None of your iCloud documents will be touched.